VBA: library not recognized after editing macro
SOLVED:
After the THIRD check on the THIRD machine (thanks ocd) i noticed that indeed there was a reference marked as "missing".
Tried to remove the reference completely - seems to work without problems.
Sorry for the bother.

Context:
Where i work we need to use VBA macros to add functionalities to AlphaCam (a cadcam program). We program the macros on development pcs, then create installers with InnoSetup, and pass them on to the operators that install them on the pcs of the machines we sell.
Problem:
Since a while ago it happens that when we install those macros on some pcs, a reference to a library inside it is broken, and the macro won't compile.
Simply editing the macro on that pc, to remove the reference and then adding it back again, works as a temporary fix.
Reinstalling the macro on that same pc represents the problem, though.
We tried putting the "fixed" macro back into the installer, and it works... until we need to edit that macro again with the dev pc. Then it breaks again.
We absolutely need to fix this, since we cannot manually edit the macro on each machine we send off (some of them don't even have the possibility to do so, depending on the license they bought for alphacam)
Please help.
Any suggestion is welcomed.

Oh yes, a thing i tried to do without success, but i forgot to mention in the post, was copying MY dll into the installer, and then putting it in the new machine when installing so... i don't believe that's a version issue

Tried using late binding after sam's suggestion, but the problem just shifts to another library...
Also, the problem seems to temporarily fix with whatever action i take in the references page (activating a completely different library that has nothing to do with the macro works too!)

As Gserg asked, i made a dump of both my references and the ones in one of the problematic machines.
GUIDs are identical, as shown in the link below
References comparison


Apparently you have different versions of that referenced library on your development machines and on the users machines, and they are not compatible GUID-wise. If you cannot fix that, switch your VBA coding to late binding.

Oh yes, a thing i tried to do without success, but i forgot to mention in the post, was copying MY dll into the installer, and then putting it in the new machine when installing so... i don't believe that's a version issue

"Putting" is the first step. Are you also registering it from the installer? If you aren't, it won't work, and if you are, you are screwing up your customers' installations because that program of theirs will stop working given that the library versions are not compatible.

Since we discovered that whatever is the action made to the references (also activating a completely different library) temporarily fix the problem i am almost sure i can say it's not a version problem.

I'm not sure how this conclusion follows from that observation. The references dialog shows you the readable names of your libraries, while it saves in your project their actual GUIDs. When you open your reference dialog on a computer that has the same-named library with a different GUID, it's going to show as MISSING. When you make your changes in that dialog, it replaces the actual GUIDs saved in your project with actual GUIDs corresponding to those display names on that computer, thus "fixing" your references for that computer. If anything, it confirms the version problem?

library does not show as missing

Open the project on your computer. Dump the list of references into a file (both .Name and .Guid). Go to the other computer where it doesn't work. Open the References dialog and fiddle with it, like you would, to fix it. Dump the list of references again into a file. Compare the files.

As i expected, all GUIDs are identical, will add screenshot of comparison in original post

After the THIRD check on the THIRD machine (thanks ocd) i noticed that indeed there was a reference marked as "missing".
Tried to remove the reference completely - seems to work without problems.
Sorry for the bother.

It is hard to give a good answer without any example code, but I'll try.
Instead of using your software, I'll use Excel and Word.
If you add a reference to Word under Tools - References, you can declare it like this
Dim WordApp as Word.Application

If you instead use late binding, like this
Dim WordApp as Object
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

it will work without references. Far more tedious to work with, but your references won't be an issue.

Tried using late binding after your suggestion, but the problem just shifts to another library...
Also, the problem seems to temporarily fix with whatever action i take in the references page (activating a completely different library that has nothing to do with the macro works too!)
